# How to estimate $P(X+Y \geq a)$?

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be random variables that only take positive values and let $a > 0$ be a real number. How can I prove that $P(X + Y \geq a) \leq P(X \geq a/2) + P(Y\geq a/2)$?

Comment: It would greatly improve your Question to add a few words of context.  Where did this problem come up?  Is there recent material you studied that it might be intended to reinforce?  Did you try to draw Venn diagrams to get a handle on how the events are related?  In many other ways you could add suitable context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have $X+Y \ge a$, we must either have $X \ge a/2$ or $Y \ge a/2$.

Indeed, if $X <a/2$ and $Y <a/2$, then $X+Y <a/2+a/2=a$.

Thus, as events, we can say that $\{ X+Y \ge a \} \subset \{X\ge a/2 \} \cup \{Y\ge a/2 \}$.

Finally, as $P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)\le P(A)+P(B)$

$$P(X+Y \ge a) \le P(\{X\ge a/2 \} \cup \{Y\ge a/2 \})\le P(X\ge a/2)+P(Y\ge a/2 )$$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see this is visually.

If you graph the possible values of $X$ and $Y$, the region that satisfies $X\geq a/2$ is rectangular, and the region that satisfies $Y \geq a/2$ is an overlapping rectangular region.  The union of those covers the first quadrant except for the square where both $X < a/2$ and $Y < a/2$.  In contrast, if you plot the region where $X+Y \geq a$, you get everything above the diagonal line passing through $(0,a)$ and $(a,0)$, which is entirely contained in the overlapping region and outside the square.

Therefore the probability of being above the diagonal is less than the probability of being in the overlapping rectangles.

To make this rigorous, simply note that for any events $A$ and $B$, if $A \subset B$ then $P(A) \leq P(B)$.  If you don't know that theorem it can be proven quickly from the axioms of probability.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe it does make that assumption, it follows from the last paragraph.  It is a list of possibilities without regard for correlations.